# In Android, how can I detect why my activity was resumed?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

I'm developing an Activity that does some of its own state management.  I'm trying to differentiate the following onResume cases:

1. New launch
2. task switch (home button long-click)
3. resume after other activity in the same application
4. wake-up after sleep
5. orientation change

Is there something in the Activity's intent, or elsewhere, that can help me differentiate these?

For the curious and some context... I'd like to preserve my internal history stack on 4 & 5.  On cases 2 & 3, I would preserve the same current page, but erase the history (allow the normal back button functionality to take over at that point).  Case 1 would initialize to the activity's internal start page (and can be detected easily enough with some help from onCreate).

Comment: I fully understand I'm not taking advantage of the Android Activity stack.  I'm doing this because my pages/internal activities are neither full screen (shared titlebar and button bar, kinda similar to a tab layout) yet still need to animate their content transitions.  The basic app spec was designed around iPhone, and I'm coming in late in the game to make the Android version, including things like the back button and orientation changes that were never assumed.

Comment: Partial solution to #4 comes from the Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF Broadcasts: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/8493895c42adb74a?pli=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something in the Activity's intent, or elsewhere, that can help me differentiate these?

Item #4 has nothing to do with `onResume()`, AFAIK.

Item #5 would be better handled via `android:configChanges` and `onConfigurationChange()` though you could "detect" it by returning something from `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and seeing if it is there in `onResume()` via `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`.

The others aren't just three cases, but probably twice that, once you start taking into account things like "being kicked out of memory to free up RAM" as a possibility.

Off the cuff, it feels like you made some unfortunate architectural decisions ("internal history stack...erase the history...allow the normal back button functionality to take over at that point"). Android is designed around lots of cheap activities, and you appear to be violating that precept. You are welcome to do so, but bear in mind that Android support for your chosen pattern may be limited.

Comment: Prior to reading this, I had implemented the onConfigurationChange() hooks to preserve history across orientation changes.  That seems to be working.

After testing, you seem to be correct about #4.

Leaving #1 and #2, which are handled in the same manner, clearing the internal history stack.

As for being kicked out of memory, I feel that is a valid case to clear the history stack and treat the new launch for what it is, a new Application instance with an empty internal history.