# Detect why activity was resumed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity called `MainActivity` that might be resumed when:

1. The app is opened for the first time.
2. `MainActivity` was already started when the user switched to another application (e.g. incoming phone call) and now came back to `MainActivity`.
3. An activity inside my app finished and `MainActivity` was resumed because it was the next activity in the stack.

I'm interested in differentiating between cases #2 and #3. Is there a way to know if the user came from my app or from a different app when `MainActivity` is resumed?

Things I've tried:

1. The examples in [In Android, how can I detect why my activity was resumed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561588/in-android-how-can-i-detect-why-my-activity-was-resumed) cover some edge cases but not these two scenarios.
2. Making sure that all activities are started using `startActivityForResult()` doesn't always work because many activities can start from frameworks (e.g. things in Google Play Services) and there's no way to track those.
3. `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` doesn't seem to differentiate between the cases where the activity is resumed from within the app vs from user interaction.

Comment: pass a flag using the intent to differentiate your startActivity from other apps?

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to identify your 2nd and 3rd point difference.

For 2nd Point

start your activity with startActivityForResult() so that while finishing other activity will give call back to you

Note : within the help of perfect way startActivityForResult() implementation you will not face any problem as you mentioned in your statements

For 3rd Point

obviously startActivityForResult() never call when you switch your app with others so that in such case you will identify with onResume()

I hope it will work for you